# Identify series which starts with a value and ends with the same value in Sql (Oracle) with overlapping time

Tags: sql, oracle11g

How can I calculate view-time for each video view?

Details:

I´m using #Oracle 11g

```
Platform ID  | Action|  Total Length of video|  Action Time
1            |  START|  0                    |  31 jul 2012 13:30:33
1            |PAUSED |  218                  |  31 jul 2012 13:30:58
1            |PLAYING|  218                  |  31 jul 2012 13:34:34
1            |  IDLE |  218                  |31 jul 2012 13:37:51
1            |  START|  0                    |  13 sep 2012 11:44:15
1            |PAUSED |  167                  |  13 sep 2012 11:45:50
1            |START  |0                      |22 aug 2012 13:19:44
1            |PAUSED |  167                  |22 aug 2012 13:20:24
2            |  START|0                      |22 aug 2012 13:23:37
2            |  IDLE |172                    |  22 aug 2012 13:26:29
2            |  START|0                      |22 aug 2012 13:26:33
2            |  STOP |172                    |  22 aug 2012 13:29:20
2            |  START|0                      |22 aug 2012 13:29:25
2|  IDLE    |276|   22 aug 2012 13:34:03
```

Problem Statement:  Above is the data about Video readership and all
the actions performed by user on a given video is captured as above.

A user can do following actions on a video.

- START: Started a video
- PAUSED: Paused a video.
- PLAYING: Start playing a paused video.
- IDLE: Video is IDLE with no action.
- STOP: Video is stopped.

I want to calculate % Video viewed per *Session.

*Session: One session can be grouped based on PlatformID and START action 
until the successive START action is encountered; provided that the
data is ordered by PlatformID and Action TIME in Ascending order.

```
Platform ID|    Action  |Total Length of video  |Action Time            |Session
1          |    START   |0                      |31 jul 2012 13:30:33   | 1
1          |    PAUSED  |218                    |31 jul 2012 13:30:58   |1
1          |    PLAYING |218                    |31 jul 2012 13:34:34   |1
1          |    IDLE    |218                    |31 jul 2012 13:37:51   |1
1          |    START   |0                      |13 sep 2012 11:44:15   |2
1          |    PAUSED  |167                    |13 sep 2012 11:45:50   |2
1          |    START   |0                      |22 aug 2012 13:19:44   |3
1          |    PAUSED  |167                    |22 aug 2012 13:20:24   |3
2          |    START   |0                      |22 aug 2012 13:23:37   |4
2          |    IDLE    |172                    |22 aug 2012 13:26:29   |4
3          |    START   |0                      |22 aug 2012 13:26:33   |5
3          |    STOP    |172                    |22 aug 2012 13:29:20   |5
4          |    START   |0                      |22 aug 2012 13:29:25   |6
4          |    IDLE    |276                    |22 aug 2012 13:34:03   |6
4          |    PLAYING |276                    |22 aug 2012 13:36:05   |6
4          |    PAUSED  |276                    |22 aug 2012 13:38:12   |6
```

Video length can be calculated as:Action Date Time Where Action=last
action of the Session which can be anything e.g. IDLE for session=
Action Date time Where Action=START.

I am not able to generate a Series for session as shown in column
session above. Please find below query as I tried.

In Nutshell,
Basically, I need to generate a session series where it should start
when Action=’START’ and STOP when Action=’START’ is encountered when
ordered by PlatformID and Action Time.

```
SELECT X.*,
    X.Action as Action_Series,
    Row_Number() Over(Partition by PlatformID Order by
    CASE WHEN Action='START' THEN 0
         WHEN Action='START' AND PrevAction != 'START' THEN 1
         ELSE 0
    END) AS Series_val
FROM
    (select  PlatformID, action, total_length, action_date_time, 
    Dense_Rank() over(Partition by 1 Order by PlatformID,action_date_time)    as   ID,
    Lag(Action) Over(Partition by 1 Order by PlatformID,action_date_time)  as PrevAction,
    Lead(Action) Over(Partition by 1 Order by PlatformID,action_date_time)  as NextAction          
    from audiovideostats 
    )X
    Order by ID;
```

Comment: Please find below Script;
CREATE TABLE audiovideostats
(
PlatformID int,
Action varchar(255),
Total_Length int,
Action_date_time timestamp
);/